# I am new to SQL Server. I created a function which action like charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL server. I am trying to create a scalar-valued function which will act like charindex.

```
IF EXISTS(SELET * FROM sysobjects 
          WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'My_search_string')
            AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
    DROP FUNCTION My_Search_String
GO

CREATE FUNCTION My_Search_String
    (@target_string varchar,
     @string varchar)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int;
    SET @result = CHARINDEX(@target_string, @string)
    RETURN @result 
END
GO
```

but I am not so sure why when I call the function like

```
select dbo.My_Search_string('cd','abcde')
go
```

it return `0` as result.
Thank you so much for your help :)
have a great day guys

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @marc_s Yes that is right ! thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you need to specify lengths on string datatypes. If you don't, it assumes length 1.

Therefore your create function line should look like

```
Create Function My_Search_String(@target_string varchar(50),@string varchar(50))
```